# cannot find symbol on getApplication() on AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask, android

I am using AsyncTask and want to use  getApplication()  to work with class Application. 
But gets error on getApplication() cannot find symbol.

my code:

```
public class  splash extends AsyncTask {
  protected config app;
  public  splash(Context context) {
  super();
  app = ((config) getApplication());
  this.context=context;
}
```

and the class that I want to use:

```
public class config extends Application
{
  public Boolean  con=true;
  public int status=-1;
  public String actNum; 
  public void onCreate()
  {
    super.onCreate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get the `Application` instance, you can initialize a member in `onCreate()` with it and have it returned by a class method:

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

  private static ApplicationConfig instance;

  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
  }

  public static ApplicationConfig getConfig() {
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Then you can retrieve this instance everywhere via:

```
ApplicationConfig conf = ApplicationConfig.getConfig();
```

Comment: Very nice way to get a global Application.
Remember to declare the application in AndroidManifest.xml
`<application
        android:name="config"
`